# Undo click event in Visnetwork in r shiny

Tags: r, graph, shiny, vis.js, visnetwork

I have created a network chart in Shiny and wanted to show details of selected node below network chart. Answer marked as correct on this link helped me in achieving that.

[Click events for VisNetwork with Shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39916465/click-events-for-visnetwork-with-shiny)

An additional thing I want to do is when the user clicks anywhere else (blank space) in the network chart, information present for the earlier clicked node should also disappear in the same manner it deselects the selected node.

Please suggest if this is possible. Below is the code

```
library(shiny)
library(visNetwork)

nodes <- data.frame(id = 1:15, label = paste("Label", 1:15),
                    group = sample(LETTERS[1:3], 15, replace = TRUE))

edges <- data.frame(from = trunc(runif(15)*(15-1))+1,
                    to = trunc(runif(15)*(15-1))+1)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$network <- renderVisNetwork({
    visNetwork(nodes, edges, 
               height = "100%", width = "100%",
               main = "") %>%
      visEvents(click = "function(nodes){
                Shiny.onInputChange('click', nodes.nodes[0]);
                ;}"
      )
  })

  output$shiny_return <- renderPrint({
    visNetworkProxy("network") %>%
      visNearestNodes(target = input$click)
  })
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  visNetworkOutput("network"), 
  verbatimTextOutput("shiny_return")  
)

shiny::shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. The trick is to pass another variable to R that kind of tell you whether you are clicking on a node or on the canvas. If you're clicking on the canvas, then `node.node` should be `undefined`. Store that information in a variable, pass it to R, and display the node information accordingly (or not).

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$network <- renderVisNetwork({
    visNetwork(nodes, edges, 
               height = "100%", width = "100%",
               main = "") %>%
      visEvents(click = "function(nodes){
                Shiny.onInputChange('click', nodes.nodes[0]);
                Shiny.onInputChange('node_selected', nodes.nodes.length);
                ;}"
      ) 
  })

  output$shiny_return <- renderPrint({
    if (!is.null(input$node_selected) && (input$node_selected == 1)) {
    visNetworkProxy("network") %>%
      visNearestNodes(target = input$click)
    } else {
      invisible()
    }
  })
}
```

### EDIT: answer to the comment

```
observe({
  input$node_selected 
  input$click
    if(!is.null(input$node_selected) && (input$node_selected == 1)){ 
      output$networkTable <- renderDataTable(data.frame(x = runif(10), 
                                                        y = runif(10))) 
    } else { 
      output$networkTable <- renderDataTable(NULL)
    } 
})
```

Comment: Also, I am using below code in my application where I am generating the profile of the person for which you click the node. Table appears upon click of a node but it does not disappear when I click elsewhere.
observeEvent(input$click, {
      if(!is.null(input$node_selected) && (input$node_selected == 1)){
        networkData <- subset(nodelist, id %in% input$click)
        output$networkTable <- renderDT(networkData)
      }
      else{
        invisible()
      }
    })

Comment: Ok, well I see two problems. First, you are not updating the `output$networkTable` properly, so it holds its value even if `input$node_selected` changes. The second problem is that when you click out of the graph, `input$click` does not update itself either, probably because it goes `undefined` in that case. I'm making an edit to my answer to help you with that.

Comment: Thank you so much for the solution. It works great for me. The main change I see here is that you did not mention any parameter in ObserveEvent. As I was running the event for input$click it was working only when node was clicked and when we clicked somewhere else it did not refreshed the values. or Am I missing something here?

Comment: Also I removed input$node_selected and input$click from first 2 lines of code and it still works. Please suggest if there would be any challenge because of this edit

Comment: I'm not using `observeEvent`, I use `observe`. `observe` will depend on all reactive variables within it. Since I wanted a dependency on `input$node_selected` and `input$click`, I put them inside. You can indeed remove `input$node_selected` since there is a `if` condition on `input$node_selected` , but you probably have to keep `input$click` if you want the profiles to be updated.

Comment: Got that. Thank you for making it clear. Also, profiles are getting updated even if I do not use input$click inside observe. In my nodelist I have a column called group and each user is assigned to one group. I want to assign some color to groups which come on chart after filter and all nodes from same group will have same color. I saw examples online but they only mention how to give one specific color to nodes but not dynamically. Can you please suggest something around that also?

Comment: Unfortunately I do not know the package visnetwork :/ I could help you with the rest since it was shiny stuff.